# OrientDB ETL transformation to create edges

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to extract data directly from Oracle to OrientDB using JDBC with ETL transformation. I have 2 tables alert and other is userRead table joined by a key column (alert_id).  I am not successful in getting edges created though vertices, indexes are successfully created with data from source.

```js
//alert:
{
  "config": {
    //  "log": "debug",
    "parallel": true
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "jdbc": { "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
              "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/dbname",
              "userName": "schema1",
              "userPassword": "password",
              "query": "select * from MC_ALERT$" }
  },
  "transformers" : [
   { "vertex": { "class":"MC_ALERT"} }
  ],
"loader": {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:/Users/dbadmin/workspace/orientdbEnprise2.1.8/databases/messaging",         
      "dbType": "graph",
      "dbUser": "admin",
      "dbPassword": "admin",
      "dbAutoCreate": true,
      "batchCommit": 1000,    
      "indexes": [
        {
          "class": "MC_ALERT",
          "fields": [ "alert_uuid:string" ],    
          "type": "UNIQUE"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}



//userRead:

{
  "config": {
    "parallel": true
  },
  "extractor" : {
   "jdbc": { "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
              "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/dbname",
              "userName": "schema1",
              "userPassword": "password",
              "query": "select a.* from MC_ALERT_USER_READ$ a, MC_ALERT$ b where a.alert_id = b.alert_uuid" }
  },
  "transformers" : [
   { "vertex": { "class":"MC_ALERT_USER_READ"} },
   { "edge": { "class": "HAS_ALERT_READ",
                "joinFieldName": "ALERT_ID",
                "lookup": "MC_ALERT.ALERT_UUID",
                "direction": "in"
            }
    }          
  ],
"loader": {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:/Users/dbadmin/workspace/orientdbEnprise2.1.8/databases/messaging", 
      "dbType": "graph",
      "dbUser": "admin",
      "dbPassword": "admin",
      "dbAutoCreate": true,
      "batchCommit": 1000,    
      "classes": [
        {"name": "MC_ALERT","extends": "V"},
        {"name": "MC_ALERT_USER_READ", "extends": "V"},
        {"name": "HAS_ALERT_READ", "extends": "E"}
      ],
      "indexes": [
        {
          "class": "MC_ALERT_USER_READ",
          "fields": [ "client_oid:string","user_oid:string","alert_id:string"],      
          //"fields": [ "alert_id:string"],    
          "type": "UNIQUE"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need to create edges to establish relationship between alert and userRead through alert_id.

Comment: Hi, which version of OrientDB are you using ?

Comment: @user5843666 Hi, can you try with "direction": "out" ?
Let me know.

Comment: Alessandro

I tried with "direction": "out". it still does not help. I only see edge class is created but not edges/relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the field names in uppercase and lowercase.

I have tried with an example and it works.

[image]

Let me know.

Comment: Can you send me your sample script that is used to get this working. I appear to use all lower case fields everyware. Just curious I am doing wrong

Comment: CloudArchitectUSA@gmail.com.

Thanks

Comment: I resolved this issue with loading data from csv files. However I am getting errors when I used JDBC.

Comment: All JDBC issues were resolved by me. Thank you for all your time.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow OrientDB was thowing errors though memory was not an issue. After restarting orientDB it resolved JDBC issue. However I am not convinced with DB restart. Logs don't give much information.